# ggplot2 Change Legend Label Values While Keeping Colors The Same

Tags: r, ggplot2

The similar questions gave solutions on how to change legend labels, by using `scale_color_manual` like this:

```
scale_fill_manual(name = "title", values = c("red","orange","blue","green"),
                     labels = c("1","2","3","4"))
```

Problem is, this method forces you to put the colors you want for the legends. If I put just labels, it won't work. How can I change the labels and keep the colors the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Data
data("iris")
#Plot
ggplot(data = iris,aes(x=Species,y=Sepal.Width,fill=Species))+
 geom_bar(stat = 'identity')+
 scale_fill_discrete(labels=letters[1:3])
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: I'm using a geom_bar() with a fill. When I try to use scale_color_discrete, the labels do not get added to the legend.

Comment: @Steveman30290 Edited. Please check and let me know if that works!